# How to add send email functionality using jQuery Mobile Phone-Gap for iPhone&Android

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have building an application using **Phone-Gap** & **jQuery Mobile** for **`iPhone`** and **`Android`**.

We need to add **`mail`** *`functionality`* to send the data as an *email* from our application.

**Is there any common plugin for email functionality in jQuery mobile.**

*`How to add mail functionality in jQuery Mobile.`*

Any links and guidance / tutorials please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure on the Android side but there is a plug-in for the iPhone side you can find at the following link on github.

https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/EmailComposer